# Message-only window not receiving messages from tray icon

Tags: c++, windows, windows-messages, trayicon

I'm trying to write a simple reusable class to encapsulte the functionality for a basic tray icon. This is my first "project" with C++, and I'm having some problems: **the message-only window created for the tray icon does not receive any message**. The icon is visible in the tray and has the correct tooltip, but clicking on it does not send any message to my invisible window.

To test if the function `WindowProcedure` was called, i added a `printf` statement, and the output is that the function is called 4 times upon creation, but no more, even if I click on the notify icon.

**Why my window does not receive any message from the tray icon?**

This is what I've managed to write:

**`TrayIcon.h`**:

```
class TrayIcon {

    public:
        TrayIcon();
        ~TrayIcon();
        void Show();
        /*...*/
        static void Initialize();


    private:
        static LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
        /*...*/    
};
```

**`TrayIcon.cpp`**:

```
// Static initializer
int TrayIcon::_idCounter = 1;
void TrayIcon::Initialize() // This method is called just once
{
    // Registers the class for the tray windows
    WNDCLASSEX wx = {};
    wx.lpfnWndProc = TrayIcon::WindowProcedure;
    wx.lpszClassName = TRAYICON_WINDOW_CLASSNAME;
    wx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    RegisterClassEx(&wx);
}

// Constructor
TrayIcon::TrayIcon()
{
    // Creates an hidden message-only window
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, TRAYICON_WINDOW_CLASSNAME, "trayiconwindow", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG)this);

    // Creates the notify icon
    NOTIFYICONDATA icon;
    memset( &icon, 0, sizeof( NOTIFYICONDATA ) ) ;
    icon.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
    icon.hWnd = hWnd;
    icon.uID = TrayIcon::_idCounter++;
    icon.uCallbackMessage = WM_TRAYICON; //Set up our invented Windows Message
    icon.uFlags = NIF_MESSAGE;
    this->_iconData = icon;
}

// Shows the tray icon
void TrayIcon::Show()
{
    // ...
    Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &this->_iconData);
}

// Processes the messages received by the hidden window for each icon
LRESULT CALLBACK TrayIcon::WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    TrayIcon* icon = (TrayIcon*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
    printf("Window Procedure called.\n\r");
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

And this is how I use the class:

```
int main()
{
    // Creates a new Tray icon
    TrayIcon::Initialize();
    TrayIcon* icon = new TrayIcon();
    icon->SetTooltip("Foo Tooltip");
    icon->SetIcon(...);
    icon->Show();

    // Waits for user input
    void* tmp;
    cin >> tmp;
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some form of message loop, not a blocking call to input something. Try the canonical message loop:

```
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly. I bet I tryed this yesterday, but it didn't work. I should definitely stop programming after midnight!